# Difference between worker thread and backgroundworker thread?

Tags: c#, java, .net, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between BackgroundWorker and Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757159/difference-between-backgroundworker-and-thread)

I was asked this question in an interview . what should be answer for this ?

Comment: It may be the similar question please have a look on it 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506838/backgroundworker-vs-background-thread

Comment: Another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757159/difference-between-backgroundworker-and-thread

Comment: @MujassirNasir, the specific answer from the first post is [Matt Davis'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1507337/1258147).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the "worker" nor "background" threads are the main/UI threads.

Unless you have more details (for example, *in the context of Language X or Framework Y*), there's no distinct difference between them. But, as I consider them:

- A **worker thread** *sounds like* it might belong to a pool of workers. In which case, it might be re-used after completing a task (and will only be stopped when the worker pool is terminated).
- A **background thread** *sounds like* it was asynchronously invoked to accomplish a single task. Possibly to save the UI thread from blocking.

Comment: this looks to me as the perfect answer. when i told the recruiter about backgroundworker , he said he did not mention backgroundworker!!

Answer (score 1):

The word "background" implies that it performs less critical tasks than non-background threads and it doesn't matter some much when they complete. In Java this can mean using a daemon thread.

Technically they are the same thing and the different is subjective.

Comment: I would no create tough relationship between words "background" and "not critical". This can be not true.

Answer (score 1):

Backgroundworker threads are most often used when you have a need to perform a long operation in the background and interact with the UI from the thread. Backgroundworker has some features that allow it to interact with the UI much easier.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWorker is a System.ComponentModel class that lets you execute a method on a separate Threadpool thread. Joe Albahari has a [good writeup on it](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker).

A worker thread is a generic term for threads spawned from your main thread that typically do work in parallel to the UI.