# Difference between Thread, ThreadPool & BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, threadpool

i many time call method with the help of thread like

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    Thread t = new Thread( MyFunction );
    t.Start();
}

static void MyFunction()
{
    //code goes here
}
```

and some time i use `ThreadPool` class also like

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
    MyFunction();
}, null);
```

but i do not understand what is the difference between calling any method with the help of thread class or `ThreadPool` class

so i am looking a good discussion about what is the difference between Thread & `ThreadPool` class.also need to know when we should use Thread class to call a method and when `ThreadPool` class to call any method ? if possible discuss also with sample code with sample situation.

another very important question is that if i start multiple thread then my application performance will become low or bad ? if yes then tell me why...?

now also tell me what is `BackgroundWorker` class and how it is different from Thread & `ThreadPool` class. how far i heard that `BackgroundWorker` class also create a separate thread to run any method. so please discuss how it is different from Thread & `ThreadPool` class and when one should go for `BackgroundWorker` class.

here is small sample code of `BackgroundWorker`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        // this allows our worker to report progress during work
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        // what to do in the background thread
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            BackgroundWorker b = o as BackgroundWorker;

            // do some simple processing for 10 seconds
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                // report the progress in percent
                b.ReportProgress(i * 10);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        });

        // what to do when progress changed (update the progress bar for example)
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            label1.Text = string.Format("{0}% Completed", args.ProgressPercentage);
        });

        // what to do when worker completes its task (notify the user)
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            label1.Text = "Finished!";
        });

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good question for [so]. It's a book's worth of information.

Comment: [Many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913487/c-sharp-downloader-should-i-use-threads-backgroundworker-or-threadpool) [existing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757159/difference-between-backgroundworker-and-thread) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008550/thread-threadpool-or-backgroundworker).

Comment: creating a thread is an expensive operation.  about 200,000 cycles to create and 100,000 cycles when you're done with it.  Using pre-created threads (e.g. the ThreadPool) is recommended.  Use BackgroundWorker when you need to offload processing from the UI thread and still require progress/cancellation--or use Task<T>.

Comment: Thread is your classic thread, just makes a new job and runs it in a new thread.

Thread pool is a way to manage the number of threads that you create.  For example, create a thread pool of 10 threads, get one from the pool, execute some job, put it back in the pool for use later. 
The BackgroundWorker class helps by setting up hooks to the UI thread to update your app. Since you can only change the UI on the main UI thread, the RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler and ProgressChangedEventHandler execute on the UI thread so you don't have to worry about looking it up first.

Comment: @Mou: You may find [an old blog post of mine](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html) useful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> but i do not understand what is the difference between calling any method with the help of thread class or ThreadPool class

The main difference is whether you manage the thread lifetime yourself (`Thread`), or you take advantage of the "pool" of threads the framework already creates.

Using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` will (often) use a thread that already exists in the system.  This means you don't have the overhead of spinning up a new thread - instead, a set of threads is already there, and your work is just run on one of them.  This can be especially beneficial if you're doing many operations which are short lived.

When you use `new Thread`, you actually spin up a new thread that will live until your delegate completes its execution.

Note that, as of .NET 4 and 4.5, I'd recommend using the `Task` and `Task<T>` types instead of making your own threads, or using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.  These (by default) use the thread pool to execute, but provide many other useful abstractions, especially with C# 5 and the `await`/`async` keywords.

> now also tell me what is BackgroundWorker class and how it is different from Thread & ThreadPool class. h

The `BackgroundWorker` class is an abstraction over the thread pool.  It uses the `ThreadPool` to queue up "work" (your `DoWork` event handler), but also provides extra functionality which allows progress and completion events to be posted back to the initial `SynchronizationContext` (which, in a GUI program, will typically be the user interface thread).  This simplifies tasks where you want to update a UI for progress or completion notifications as background "work" is running on a background thread.

Comment: Curious why the downvoting here... :)

Comment: i guess all thread classes are by default foreground thread but BackgroundWorker only deals with background thread....why ?? give some insight about fore ground & background thread if possible.

Comment: @Thomas The thread pool uses backgroudn threads.  In general, that's what people want - the only way to get foreground threads is to make your own.

Comment: Thread t = new Thread( MyFunction );
t.Start(); when we create thread with thread class then what is default type of thread is created....is it background or foreground ??

Comment: @Mou Foreground - see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0(v=vs.110).aspx